# Where can I find a PDF scan of Rahabi Ezekiel's "Travancore Hebrew New Testament" or "Book of the Gospel Belonging to the Followers of Jesus"?

Tags: bible-translation, reference-request, new-testament, hebrew, gospel

It is a polemical rabbinic translation of the entire New Testament, allegedly in an uneven and faulty Hebrew, and with a strong anti-Christian bias.

Comment: Sounds like the opposite thing a TruthSeeker would want, but good luck!

Answer (score 1):

It's not polemical and has no anti-Christian bias.

Thomas Yeates, the scribe who copied it from the original (today MS heb. Oo.1.32, held at Cambridge University Library) made numerous mistakes, which is the only reason why the Hebrew is faulty.

You can download the MS here:

https://www.digitalcollections.manchester.ac.uk/view/MS-GASTER-HEBREW-01616/1